# Use DHCP only one time

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

This is my `/etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0` file.

```
#auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 172.16.68.75
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 172.16.68.0
broadcast 17.16.68.255
gateway 172.16.68.1
```

I currently have it setup to use a static IP address, however I really prefer to use DHCP so I can use MAC address reservations and manage them from my router.  The only problem I’m having is, a couple of times a day this server goes down, and the logs indicate it is trying to renew its ip.  Is there a way to do this, either at boot or the network starting?

Comment: Set longer lease times for DHCP?

Comment: @muru do you have an example?

Comment: Not without knowing what DHCP server you're using.

Comment: My mistake, the lease time is set on the *server*, not the client, so I guess that won’t work.

Comment: Why won't it work ? Have you tried ?

Comment: Is it a problem that the server renews lease when rebooting? Any sane DHCP will give you the same ip-address that you have earlier, as long as the lease time hasn't expired ... and as long as you have enough ip-addresses in your DHCP scope, you will receive your old ip-address long time after the lease has expired.